# LinkedHashMap to Pojo

Tags: java, pojo, linkedhashmap

I have a variable that is a linked hash map. Its like:

```
"message": "something"
"code": "0"
```

and I have a pojo:

```
String message;
Integer code;
//getters and setters
```

Is there any library that converts a linkedhasmap into a pojo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) has a [`populate()` method](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29) that moves map values into a bean.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate map and create a list of POJO object.